# How to use rootScope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data in my commonservice and I want to use the data in my template and I will assign a rootscope and use it but it isn't working right now and I am not sure what's wrong can anyone please suggest help.

My js:

```
function addGoogleAddress(id, data, scope) {
    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(id));
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        if (place && place.address_components) {
            for (var i = 0; i < (place.address_components.length); i++) {
                if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'locality') {
                    data.city.key = '1001';
                    data.city.name = place.address_components[i].long_name.toString();
                } else if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                    data.state.key = '1001';
                    data.state.name = place.address_components[i].long_name.toString();
                } else if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'country') {
                    data.country.key = '1001';
                    data.country.name = place.address_components[i].long_name.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $timeout(function () {
        $('#' + id).removeAttr('placeholder');
    }, 500);
    $rootScope.data = data;
}
```

My controller:

```
  console.log($rootScope.data)
```

Here i am getting undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not broadcast data directly, you need to broadcast event and pass parameter like follows,

Note: I am assuming here you have injected dependency

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('eventName',data);
```

Then in controller like follows -

```
$scope.$on('eventName',function(event,data){
console.log('data---',data);
})
```

Comment: Hi Mr.Helper,how can i use this data in my view?is it enough with this ng-model=data.city.name   or i should call the function.

Comment: You can not directly use this data. You need to assign data to ng-modal
eg. $scope.modalName  = data;

Comment: How can i call this function  $scope.$on('eventName',function(event,data){
console.log('data---',data);
})   ?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Helper ,,,,,can you pls answer my question

Comment: Its not function, Its an event it will automatically get called once you broadcast event

Comment: but my case it is getting fired only after clearing my google place value in my input.

Comment: it should be called whenever you call addGoogleAddress function. If not then there might be any issues with code above it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128321/discussion-between-mr-helper-and-nlr-p).

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('ctrl1',['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.xyz = $rootScope.xyz;
    //console.log($scope.xyz); hey
}]);

app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.xyz ="hey";
})
```